# How to choose feedforward architecture for few number of features but very large instance?

Tags: neural-network, bigdata, features

Assume I have `1 million` of data instance and each instance contains `100` feature. For each instance, I also have a lable.

The size of `X` will  be `1,000,000 X 100` and the `y` will be `1,000,000 X 1`. The value of `y` is binary.

Under this case, how to pick feedforward architecture?

Such as `100-50-1` or `5000-2500-50-1`, any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no thumb-rule to determine a NN architecture for a specific problem. First, see if any other individual has implemented an NN architecture for your problem. Building up on that knowledge, conduct various experiments until you are left with a model which performs satisfactorily on given testing data.

Answer (score 0):

Is your set of possible labels discrete or continuous?

If it's discrete and you have L possible different labels, then you should have L units in the output layer (then do a softmax if you want probabilities).

If it's continuous, then you should have 1 output unit.

Lastly, the number of units in the input layer is equal to the flattened dimension of one instance of the input. So if your data is 100 dimensions, then you must have 100 units in the input layer.

Comment: it is a binary classification problem. I update it. thanks.

Comment: Ok! If all images this model will see are either label 0 or 1, then a single output unit with a sigmoid will suffice. So, for example, we can have Pr(Y=1|X) = the output of the sigmoid and Pr(Y=0|X)=1-Pr(Y=1|X)